# Facebook: Count number of status update shares on your own fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sharing

I've got a website and a Facebook fan page for it. Basically, I want to create a status update  on the fan page, for people to share. Then on the website, I want to dynamically calculate the number of 'Shares' that the status update is receiving. Not the likes or comments, just the shares. Is this a possible task? If so, how could this be achieved?

Would appreciate all the help, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

After getting `read_stream` permisson, you can access the post stats via Graph Api:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_ID]_[POST_ID]?access_token=[YOUR ACCESS TOKEN]
```

You will see shares count in json output:

```
"shares": {
    "count": 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. How do I get manage_pages and read_insight permissions? Does FB has instructions on how to set up or get these permissions?

Comment: I edited answer, you must get `read_stream` permission. Test it with Graph API Explorer http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Okay. Any chance you could explain what read_stream permissions are and how to get them? Also how would I get the Post_ID? Sorry - I'm new to this, I would have thought it'd be a relatively simple task as this would only be used for my own fan page

Comment: I think you must start from scratch http://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/